# what does yield as assignment do? myVar = (yield)

Tags: python, yield

I'm familiar with yield to return a value thanks mostly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/can-somebody-explain-me-the-python-yield-statement)

but what does yield do when it is on the right side of an assignment?

```
@coroutine
def protocol(target=None):
   while True:
       c = (yield)

def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args,**kwargs):
        cr = func(*args,**kwargs)
        cr.next()
        return cr 
    return start
```

I came across this, on the code samples of [this blog](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/29/co-routines-as-an-alternative-to-state-machines/), while researching state machines and coroutines.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `yield` statement used in a function turns that function into a "generator" (a function that creates an iterator). The resulting iterator is normally resumed by calling `next()`. However it is possible to send values to the function by calling the method `send()` instead of `next()` to resume it:

```
cr.send(1)
```

In your example this would assign the value `1` to `c` each time.

`cr.next()` is effectively equivalent to `cr.send(None)`

Comment: Just to note, before being able to call `send()` on a generator, you have to call `next()` to actually start it, or you'll get a TypeError saying: `TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator`

Answer (score 12):

You can send values to the generator using the `send` function.

If you execute:

```
p = protocol()
p.next() # advance to the yield statement, otherwise I can't call send
p.send(5)
```

then `yield` will return 5, so inside the generator `c` will be 5.

Also, if you call `p.next()`, `yield` will return `None`.

You can find more information [here](http://antroy.blogspot.com/2007/04/python-coroutines.html).

Answer (score 0):

- `yield` returns a stream of data as per the logic defined within the generator function.
- However, send(val) is a way to pass a desired value from outside the generator function.

#### p.next() doesn't work in python3, next(p) works (built-in) for both python 2,3

p.next() doesn't work with python 3, gives the following error,however it still works in python 2.

```
Error: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Here's a demonstration:

```py
def fun(li):
  if len(li):
    val = yield len(li)
    print(val)
    yield None
    

g = fun([1,2,3,4,5,6])
next(g) # len(li) i.e. 6 is assigned to val
g.send(8) #  8 is assigned to val
```