# How is x = yield f() different to x = f()?

Tags: python

I'm going through the source of a library. The question I have is general and not specific to the library. The code I'm wondering about looks like this:

```
class SpiderMiddlewareManager(MiddlewareManager):
    # ...
    def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
        return self._process_chain('process_start_requests', start_requests, spider)

class
    # ...
    def open_spider(self, spider, start_requests=(), close_if_idle=True):
        # ...
        start_requests = yield self.scraper.spidermw.process_start_requests(start_requests, spider)
        # ...
```

My question is: How is `start_requests = yield self.scraper.spidermw.process_start_requests(...)` different to `start_requests = self.scraper.spidermw.process_start_requests(...)` since `self.scraper.spidermw.process_start_requests` already returns a value. If my understanding is correct, `open_spider` isn't a generator.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this is a dup - `open_spider` shouldn't be a generator. So I don't see how my question is a duplicate.

Comment: `open_spider` is a generator.

Comment: But what value is `start_requests` supposed to take?

Comment: @Kate whatever is sent - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2022218/3001761

Comment: It looks like the method using the `yield` call is decorated with a `@deferred.inlineCallbacks`, which means it's a twisted coroutine. The `yield` allows it to return control to the twisted reactor while blocking I/O runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an important detail missing from your question - the library you're looking at is written on top of [`twisted`](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), which is an asynchronous networking framework. The complete method declaration actually looks like this:

```
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def open_spider(self, spider, start_requests=(), close_if_idle=True):
        assert self.has_capacity(), "No free spider slot when opening %r" % \
            spider.name
        log.msg("Spider opened", spider=spider)
        nextcall = CallLaterOnce(self._next_request, spider)
        scheduler = self.scheduler_cls.from_crawler(self.crawler)
        start_requests = yield self.scraper.spidermw.process_start_requests(start_requests, spider)
```

The [`defer.inlineCallbacks`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks.html) decorator does some magic with all the calls that used `yield`. Essentially it lets you write asynchronous code that would normally use callbacks, in a way that *looks* synchronous:

> `inlineCallbacks` helps you write `Deferred`-using code that looks like a
>   regular sequential function. This function uses features of Python 2.5
>   generators. If you need to be compatible with Python 2.4 or before,
>   use the `deferredGenerator` function instead, which accomplishes the
>   same thing, but with somewhat more boilerplate. For example:
>
> ```
>  @inlineCallBacks    
>  def thingummy():
>      thing = yield makeSomeRequestResultingInDeferred()
>      print thing #the result! hoorj!
> ```
>
> When you call anything that results in a `Deferred`, you can simply `yield` it; your generator will
>   automatically be resumed when the Deferred's result is available. The
>   generator will be sent the result of the `Deferred` with the `send`
>   method on generators, or if the result was a failure, `throw`.
>
> Your `inlineCallbacks`-enabled generator will return a `Deferred` object,
>   which will result in the return value of the generator (or will fail
>   with a failure object if your generator raises an unhandled
>   exception). Note that you can't use return result to return a value;
>   use `returnValue(result)` instead. Falling off the end of the generator,
>   or simply using return will cause the `Deferred` to have a result of
>   `None`.

If you dig into the `process_start_requests` call, you'll find it ultimately calls `scrapy.util.defer.process_chain`, which returns a `Deferred`:

```
def process_chain(callbacks, input, *a, **kw):
    """Return a Deferred built by chaining the given callbacks"""
    d = defer.Deferred()
    for x in callbacks:
        d.addCallback(x, *a, **kw)
    d.callback(input)
    return d
```