# What does "val = yield xxx" mean in Python

Tags: python, generator, tornado, yield

I know what does yield do when we write say

```
while True:
    yield i
    i += 1
```

But what does it mean when we say

```
def foo():
    A = yield B
```

? What would be the value of A then?

The reason why I asked this question is because this is how things are done in tornado: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html

In Tornado, I see a lot of examples saying

```
document = yield http_client.fetch('...')
```

I know document should be the content fetched by the client. By for now I'm trying to understand how it is implemented - I searched for many examples about but couldn't find any one explaining how does "A = yield B" work. By looking Tornado's source code I couldn't understand it myself. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: With the recent edit, a closer duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022218/what-does-yield-as-assignment-do-myvar-yield